# Autolayout differences between iOS 8 and iOS 9

Tags: ios, autolayout

If I run the same code on iOS 8 and iOS 9 the layout comes out differently. The icon and label should be even.

I'm using a custom font so I'd assume the font size / height is the same in both OSes. If I adjust the spacing constraint to be right on 9 it shows up wrong on 8.

Any ideas?

#### Update

Here is the existing constraint:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like iOS 9 is using the baselines and iOS 8 is using the centers

Comment: What constraints have you set?

Comment: @dan thanks for the info. I'm not sure how to adjust my constraints based on that info yet, but I'll play around with it.

Comment: @Paulw11 - I'll update my question to include the existing constraint.

Comment: It looks like you should be using "center" rather than "top" alignment. I think you have a difference between the frames that are being calculated in iOS 8 and iOS 9.  While running you app, in Xcode go to the Debug menu and select "View debugging->Show view frames" and you will see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 that helps. It looks like the layouts are different (centered in the box vs pushed to the top). I didn't want to use center alignment since the label could end up being two lines long in which case I wanted the checkmark to still be at top. I'll have to play around with those frames some more.

Comment: Are you constraining the label's height in any way?  What content hugging priority is set on the label?  You could also try a constraint of label.baseline=checkmark.top with the constant = to 1/2 of the checkmark height

Comment: What is the number of lines set to on the label?  0 or 2?

Comment: 0 since it should be variable to fit the entire text.